# Many integral points on quartic models of elliptic curve via differences of squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, experimental-mathematics

Pick fourth power free integer $n$ ($p^4$ doesn't divide $n$).

Represent $n$ as difference of possibly negative integer squares
$n=v_i^2-u_i^2$.

The goal is to find quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients
(possibly square) $f(x)$ maximizing the number of solutions to
$f(x)=u_i$.

Solutions are integral points on the elliptic curve $n=y^2-f(x)^2$.

Unless one can use the group law and scale rationals (related to fourth
power free), boundedness is open problem, so I am interested in explicit
records.

In terms of rank, my current record is $37$ points (not counting
the sign of $x$) on $ y^2-(x^2-565215^2)^2=40224510201185827416900$
of rank $9$.

This was found by expressing $u_i=u_i'^2-v_i'^2$ and checking for
the most common $v_i'$.

Also, what do heuristic say about this record(s)?

Comment: $n = 440224510201185827416900$ is equal to the product of the first $11$ primes squared. I tried your idea for product with less than $11$ primes squared, but achieved nothing of interest. So I wondered how you came across $n = 40224510201185827416900$? And how are you able to compute with an $n$ of this order of magnitude. It seems to demand a prohibitively long computation.

Comment: Other than that I really like your ideas of producing elliptic curves of high rank. This one, as well as the previous idea, seems quite novel to me.

Comment: @JesperPetersen The record was found in less than 15 minutes. Contact me via mail if you want the sage code. There might be some structure in the divisors leading to better records - chose suitable primes.

Comment: Actually there was a bug in my own Sage code. I did notice a vague pattern, which I reported in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

From realizing that

$$440224510201185827416900 = \prod_{\text{p prime} \leq 31} p^2$$ I noticed a vague pattern that might be of interest. Let

$$n_P = \prod_{\text{p prime} \leq P} p^2$$ and consider that curves $E_P: n_P = y^2 - f(x)$.

Now, the number of integral points on $E_P$, which we can denote $S_P$, grows monotonically  like this. 
$$
S_3 = 1, 
S_5 = 3,
S_7 = 6,
S_{11} = 9,
S_{13} = 10,
S_{17} = 14,
S_{19} = 30.$$ For $S_{23}$ and $S_{29}$ there is no growth compared to $S_{19}$, but as you have noticed $S_{31} = 37$.

I wonder if there is an explanation for this. Maybe your Sage code can extend the computation beyond $S_{31}$?

Comment: For S_17 I get 15 points and for S_19 get 31.

Comment: My implementation uses a lot of RAM (on purpose, to save time) and I get out of memory on my machine beyond. Maybe 64 or 128 GB will be enough for beyond. Too lazy to increase the swap or use SQL.

Comment: My computation of $S_{19}$ contains these 30 points:[[73269, 5359083114],[60025, 3593741690],[33853, 1136794966],[25095, 620562810], [16611,266829654],[15701, 237447574],[11775,129741690],[10805,107912810],[8617, 65700614],[7035, 41372310], [6543, 34913274], [5425, 22370810], [5255,20749690],[4831, 17086586],[4641,15638406],[4365,13775190],[185,13394810],[273, 13367046],[495,13250310],[4221,12926634],[1069,12655786],[1311,12293754],[1477,12014954],[1875,11279190],[1933,11168086],[2187,10688106],[3465,10077690],[3379,9934166],[2807, 9799174],[2883, 9747114]]. Which one is missing?

Comment: What is your f(x)? Is (3045, 9699690) on your quartic, it is on mine (and your points are on mine).

Comment: My $f(x)$ is $x^2 - 3045^2$. $(3045, 9699690)$ is indeed on the quartic. I must investigate how I could miss that point.

Comment: Mine f(x) is the same :) Check for minus and observe that (-x)^2 works too, I take abs().

Comment: If n is square you get extra point with sqrt(n).

Comment: Yes, I understand where the extra point comes from. But unfortunately it seems to be infeasible to investigate the family $E_P$ much further, as the number of divisors of $N_P$ grows too fast. Unless there is a way to ignore certain divisors somehow.

Comment: Indeed it is exponential, but sufficiently powerful computer/cluster might solve some cases (one can trade time for memory). btw, I suggest in your answer to make more clear your conjecture is for the specific algorithm, not for all $f(x)$.

Comment: Another possibility is to test square of product of few primes to check if there is some pattern, say $p,2p+1,p^2+2$.

Comment: Added answer with idea for faster records.

Comment: Was your new idea deleted again?

Comment: Yes, it leads to isogenous curve, so it is useless... If you didn't see it I might tell it to you.

Comment: Actually the curves are even isomorphic in the new idea.